# Two functions in Flask to plot data independently

Tags: python, flask

**How do I create separate functions (within index function in the controller.py) so I can create two independent plots with two independent files that I load independently?**

In other words, I would like the user take the following steps:

1. Upload the Training file
2. Click the 'Plot' button to plot
3. Now upload the Test file
4. Click the 'Plot' button to plot.

Both plots should appear on the same HTML template. Both files will use the same plotting function (or now). Ideally, I would like to use different functions.

Here's how the input HTML looks like:

[image]

The function to plot is the following:

```
def compute_mean_std(filename=None):
    # data = np.loadtxt(os.path.join('uploads', filename))
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join('uploads', filename))
    sns.set_style('darkgrid')
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True)
    ax[0].plot(df.index, df.x, color="red")
    ax[1].plot(df.index, df.y, color="blue")
    ax[2].plot(df.index, df.z, color="teal")
    ax[0].legend(numpoints=1, loc=1)
    ax[1].legend(loc=1)
    ax[2].legend(loc=1)

    # Check static folder:
    if not os.path.isdir('static'):
        os.mkdir('static')
    else:
        for plotfilename in glob.glob(os.path.join('static', '*.png')):
            os.remove(plotfilename)
    plotfile = os.path.join('static', str(time.time()) + '.png')
    plt.savefig(plotfile)
    return plotfile
```

While the controller has the following code:

```
from compute import compute_mean_std as compute_function
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = Average(request.form)
    filename = None  # default
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # Save uploaded file on server if it exists and is valid
        if request.files:
            file = request.files[form.filename.name]
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                # Make a valid version of filename for any file ystem
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                                       filename))

        result = compute_function(filename)
    else:
        result = None

    return render_template("view.html", form=form, result=result)
```

Right now both plot the same plots.

[image]

Comment: it looks like job for JavaScript/Ajax

Comment: maybe they plots the same because you draw two times the samr form but yoy should have two forms with different fields names.Show HTML.

Comment: @furas Is right. When ajax call or POST response you have to differentiate `Training` and `Test`

Comment: I know why they do so. I would like to know "HOW" I should create two forms? Can you please help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: as @RajaSimon showed you have to use two inputs with different names to recognize which file was uploaded. Some people use two different names for buttons to recognize which button was clicked. Probably you will have to use cookies to remember which file was uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So How do we differentiate the two file uploads.? The option is we have to create two file input...

```
<input type="file" name="file_training">
<input type="file" name="file_test">
```

and in your view function you have to check which file is user uploaded

```
# Inside POST method
file_training = request.files.get('file_training')
file_test = request.files.get('file_test')
return jsonify({"file_training": file_training, "file_test": file_test})
```

HTML

In your ajax success keep track of which have the values.